# SQL Server Native Client ODBC Connection Fails

Tags: sql-server, odbc, client, native-client

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue where some clients can connect and others cannot.

1. Server and Database is online, Browser started, Named Pipes & TPC/IP enabled
2. All users use the same SQL Account and Password
3. Connection to database from SSMS works
4. Local firewall rules are from GPO and match all clients
5. Instance is configured to allow remote connections
6. Server does not have firewall rule blocking any client IP involved

We create a SQL Server Native Client 11 ODBC connection.  On some clients the connection comes back with Success and others come back TESTS FAILED!

The full text of the message is:

```
Running connectivity tests ...
Attempting connection
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes
Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5].
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login Timeout expired
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related
or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL
Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more
information see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Any ideas on why some clients are not able to connect?

Comment: Perhaps an ODBC trace on the failing client machines might tell you something?  Here is an example - https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH43268

Comment: other things to try here - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23704/easy-way-to-check-connectivity-to-sql-server-from-client

Comment: ssms works from another machine?

Comment: SSMS connections (Using the SQL account) work from all of the clients.  The problem appears to be related to the ODBC Native Client.  I am in the process of running a trace now.

Comment: We turned on tracing and tested the connection but no output file was generated.

Comment: What port number is it using and are you specifying that in odbc connection? It may be using a non standard port. I would also disable firewall temporarily to see if that helps.